# SQL SELECT from multiple tables or JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, syntax

I have two tables from which I need to get data in the same `SELECT` output. The thing is that I need to limit the amount of results.

Say I have an `ID` column that is unique in `table1`, but in `table2` it has many rows with that `ID`.

Now I just want to list how many different `ID`s I have in `table1` and some other information stored in `table2`.

How can I get the desired output I show in the end?

To make my idea clear I used a "messenger" database for an example.

Tables

T1

```
Id_thread            Date
1                    13Dic
2                    12Dic
```

T2

```
Id_thread            Message        Name
1                    Hi             Someone
1                    Hi to you      Someone
2                    Help me?       Someother
2                    Yes!           Someother
```

Desired output

```
T1.Id_thread         T2.Name     T1.Date
1                    Someone     13Dic
2                    Someother   12Dic
```

Comment: What is the limiting condition for table 2? Max one row? or some other condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t1.Id_thread, t2.Name, t1.Date
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.Id_thread = t2.Id_thread
GROUP BY t1.Id_thread
```

Note that if `Name` is the same for all rows in `t2` that have the same `Id_thread`, that column probably should be in `t1`. If you fix that, you don't need the `JOIN`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. But the one who made the original App did it this way, dunno why.

Comment: I'll try this and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

I'd join and use `distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id_thread, t2.name, t1.date
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 ON t1.id_thred = t2.id_thread
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.Id_thread, T2.Name, T1.Date 
FROM T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.Id_thread = T2.Id_thread
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.Id_thread,T2.Name,T1.Date from T1 
inner join T2 on T1.Id_thread = T2.Id_thread
group by T1.Id_thread
order by T1.Id_thread
```

Comment: I think this will give multiple results for each ID.

Comment: No it will not because of `group by` clause in the query @AK47

Comment: Oh! correct. Still I think this will give error, no aggregate functions used for columns which are not there in group by.

Comment: Not it will not give you such an error in mysql. But in case of sql i doubt

Comment: So which records it will take for duplicate one?

Comment: Something like this was tried by with no GROUP BY. I'll see what happens

Comment: @AK47 MySQL has `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` turned off by default, so it allows this. It will get values from random rows of duplicates. But that's not a problem for this application, the dupliates all have the same `Name` value.

Comment: OK. I should have gone through some documents before downvoting.

Comment: When this was tried (with no group by) I got a result for every row of T2. In my case I did ORDER BY date DESC.

Comment: you should include a brief explanation along with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how you want the limit the results from Table 2. Considering you just want one row, you can use a CROSS APPLY:

```
Select T1.Id_thread,T2Table.Name,T1.Date From T1 
Cross Apply (Select Top 1 T2.Name From T2 Where T2.Id_thread=T1.Id_thread) T2Table
```

You can specify other conditions in the inner Select statement if you wish.